# How to use <meta http-equiv="REFRESH"> to display the current time

Tags: html

I need to use  `<meta http-equiv="REFRESH">` to display the current time as it changes.
This is what i tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function change_time()
    {
    var d = new Date();
    var curr_hour = d.getHours();
    var curr_min = d.getMinutes();
    var curr_sec = d.getSeconds();  
    if(curr_hour > 12)
    curr_hour = curr_hour - 12;
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = curr_hour+':'+curr_min+':'+curr_sec;
    }
    change_time();
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Current time is :</td>
    <td id="time"></td>
    <tr>
    </table> 

    </body>
</html>
```

The page refreshes itself every second but it doesn't not show the functions value.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<body onload="change_time()">
```

Remove `change_time();` line just before closing `</script>` tag.

Edit:

You have forgot to call your javascript method on load/refresh of page.

To do so -  use onload() event of body tag in html.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call your Javascript function when you have loaded the page. You can achieve that by using the `onload` attribute on the `body` node:

```
<body onload="change_time()">
```

See also: [How do I call a JavaScript function on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842614/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-on-page-load)