# on webpage enter, display html browse file dialogue?

Tags: file, input, pageload

I have the following code giving a manual browse file dialogue:

input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" onchange="fileSelectHandler()"

Is there a way to call this (perhaps using javascript?) automatically on page enter so that the user is given the browse file dialogue upon entering the webpage?

Thanks!

Comment: code please...?
any way...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842614/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-on-page-load might help

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" onchange="fileSelectHandler()" style="visibility:hidden" />
```

and the jquery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[type='file']").trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

This requires permissions from user to allow pop ups for security reasons...
[Jquery trigger file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793014/jquery-trigger-file-input)
http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/upload-forms-threat/