# running javascript on page load/close

Tags: javascript

I am a total amateur to javascripts.
I have the scripts in this form.

```
<!-- BEGIN code-->
<script type="text/javascript">a_b='2385y283yf28332';</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://somewebsite.com/jsclients
/jac.js"charset="utf-8"></script>
<!-- END Code -->
```

Currently, in order for the code to be executed (the code produces a pop up) a click needs to occur on my web page.

I wanted to know, if theres some method which will execute the code when user lands on my website (without clicking anywhere on my site)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sure, pop it up on page load. Easily searchable. And very, very annoying.

Comment: Every site with unsolicited popups goes into my list of sites to never ever visit, ever again, for any reason, ever.

Comment: The code in `jac.js` runs when the page is loaded. You need to look at the contents of that script, and change it to display the popup immediately instead of binding a click handler.

Comment: Agree with @DaveNewton  Pop up a window or modal is annoying.

Comment: The popup is unique per visitor so its not too annoying.
also to add...i dont have access to the .JS

Comment: not possible to simulate a click on webpage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I call a JavaScript function on page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842614/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-on-page-load)

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function yourFunction()
{
alert("Page loaded!");
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="yourFunction()">
</body>
</html>
```

this will sure works fine.try this.

Comment: so this is correct?
<script>
function yourFunction()
those 2 javascripts in here}
</script>

?

Comment: hmm.looks like you want the alerted code from your 2 javascript? try to remove this `<script> function yourFunction() those 2 javascripts in here} </script>` and just change the function on the `onload` part of yours. Call the function which trigger the popup message.

Comment: you want the `alert` to show when you `click` on any part of the page?

Comment: no, all i want is that code to be executed without getting a click on webpage, currently requires a click on webpage to execute code (that java script, which i dont have access to, seems to monitor the site for a click)

Comment: then `onload` will work. why no access? can you find that `code` on your two js file? is the code coming from here?  `http://somewebsite.com/jsclients
/jac.js` can you give me the real `url`?

Comment: I dnt have access to the fule but real url is "http://ads.juicyads.com/jsclients/jac.js

Answer (score -1):

Simply in your javascript you can put

```
document.onload(function(){
    //DO STUFF HERE
});
```

And for when your page unloads,

```
document.unload(function(){
    //DO STUFF HERE
});
```

Comment: Why recommend jQuery, then not use it? You probaby attrated a down vote because you recommended a library that isn't tagged or in the OP.

Comment: @RobG That too, but mostly the fact that it was recommended and then not even utilised.