# How to know when an object within a page has completed loading

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page where there are buttons that lead to html content being loaded within the host page using an object tag.

Is there a way of the host page knowing when the content has completed loading?

The reason is so that when:

- button is clicked a display loading gif across the host page
- html is loaded into object
- hide the loading gif

The host page loads. Buttons on the host lead to content to being loaded into an object:

```
<script>
    .... check which button is pressed and assign path to target 
    var objectContent = "<object type=\"text/html\" data=\"" + target + "\" height=\"500px\" width=\"100%\" style=\"overflow:auto; min-height:400px;\"></object>";
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = objectContent;
</script>
```

What I trying to figure out is how to know when the content has completed loading into the object.

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded`, `window.onload`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call a JavaScript function on page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842614/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-on-page-load)

Comment: @GeoffJames I am not sure this is a duplicate. It is not the initial loading of an object - it is loading html content into an object after the host page has already loaded. See uodate.

Comment: Thanks @RGriffiths - now the question's been updated it's become a bit more apparent as to what the OP is asking

Comment: @Tushar This is fine for the initial loading of the host page, but I am trying to work out how to know when additional content has completed loading within the page when a button is pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. Include the onload into the object tag. And then add a function to hide the loader.

```
var out = "<object ... onload=\"contentLoaded(this)\"></object>";

<script>
    function contentLoaded() {
        $(".loader").hide();
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using JavaScript to check when the DOM is fully loaded like this:

```
window.onload = function () { alert("It's loaded!") }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is fine for the initial loading of the host page, but I am trying to work out how to know when additional content has completed loading within the page when a button is pressed.