# How can I make a function which executes on page loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JS function that I need to execute it when page loads. Here is the function:

```
function myfunc(){
    alert('something');
}
```

Noted that I also need to have a name for it. Because I need to call it after page loading again *(on click of a element)*.

So in short, I need to define a function which executes both on page loading and when user click on `$('.myclass')` element. How can I do that?

Comment: Functions can be passed and referred by refrence in JS ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call a JavaScript function on page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842614/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-on-page-load)

Comment: You can use two event listeners
https://api.jquery.com/click/
https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the call to that function in both the click handler for the `.myclass` elements, and also directly in a `script` tag, right before the `</body>`. Something like this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.myclass').click(myfunc); // on click
    });

    myfunc(); // on load
</script>
```

Comment: When you say *right before the `</body>`*, why would you even add a ready state around?

Comment: @eisbehr because habit :) but you're right, that wouldn't technically be needed either.

Comment: @eisbehr Do you mean `$(function() {` is redundant ?

Comment: When placing the script right before `</body>` it can be omitted, yes

Comment: Just for my information, if I want to write your script after `</body>`, do I need to write it `$(function() {`? why?

Comment: Putting it there is invalid. The `<script>` tag needs to go inside either the `<head>` or `<body>`. If you put the tag anywhere but right before the `</body>` you'll need to put it in the ready handler, as the DOM wouldn't be ready at that point

Answer (score 2):

Try below code, It calls Click me on load and on button click as well.
Hope this helps

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('document load')
  clickMe();
});
$('.button').click(function(){
clickMe();
});
function clickMe(){
  console.log('Clicked');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" > click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

how about `<body onload="myfunc()">` and your function in the `<head>` element:

```
<script>
function myfunc(){
    alert('something');
}
</script>
```

and then to call it from button

```
<button onclick="myfunc()">Click me</button>
```