# Hide input according to another input value

Tags: javascript, html, input, hide, show

I have this simple form:

```
<form align="center" onload="chk()" name="form" action="" method="post" id="form">  
  <input type="text" name="quantt" id="quantt" value="">    
  <input type="text" name="avail" id="avail" value="">  
</form>
```

the "avail" input is auto-filled from a php script. My question is How can I hide or disable the "quantt" input if the "avail" value is empty **on loading** of the form ?

I've tried this function but it didn't work :-(

```
function chk() {
    var ava = document.form.avail;
    if (ava.value == "") {
        document.getElementById("quantt").type = "hidden";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("quantt").type = "text";
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use below function

```
<script>
    function chk() 
    {
        if ( $("#avail").val() == "" ) {
            $("#quantt").attr("hide", true)
        } else {
            $("#quantt").attr("hide", false)
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Call it on window on load like suggested by pedro

Comment: again perfect! thank you so much. I use this function.

Comment: If this works for you kindly consider the upvote or acceptance for the answer... So people would know that this is accepted or upvoted answer...

Answer (score 1):

The chk() function seems to work fine. Try to call it using window.onload, like:

```
window.onload = function() {
    chk();
};
```

For more information refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842614/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-on-page-load#3842895) question.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked fine with window.onload.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Element.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) you can call your function `chk` on `body` load:

```js
document.querySelector('body').onload = function chk() {
  var qte = document.getElementById('quantt')
  document.getElementById('avail').type = (qte.value === '') ? 'hidden' : 'text';
};
```

```html
<form align="center" name="form" action="" method="post" id="form">  
  <input type="hidden" name="quantt" id="quantt" value="">    
  <input type="text" name="avail" id="avail" value="">    
</form>
```