# I am trying to convert this from an on click function to onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that generates a csv file from html table data. The script below forces a download when the link class export is clicked. I would like this to happen automatically when the page loads. Is this something that is possible?

```
$(".export").on('click', function (event) {
    // CSV
    var args = [$('#output>table'), 'heartbeat.csv'];

    exportTableToCSV.apply(this, args);

    // If CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false
    // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call a JavaScript function on page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842614/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-on-page-load)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jQuery, there is a `.ready()` listener function that you can set up like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var args = [$('#output>table'), 'heartbeat.csv'];    
    exportTableToCSV.apply(this, args);
});
```

I highly encourage you to review the documentation, here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/