# display message on a jsp for interval of a minute

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a message that I am pushing from the controller to the JSP. I want to check if the message is not null then display it to the JSP page for a minute.

This is my controller snippet

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("dashboard");
                        mav.addObject("message", "Login Successful");
                        return mav;
```

I am using it in the view as shown this way

```
<h4 align="center">${message} </h4>
```

How can I display it for an interval of a minute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript's setTimeout method to call a callback function that can  hide the text after 1 minute.

- Assign an id to you H4 tag  `<h4 align="center" id="msgid">${message} </h4>`
- Set timeout on body on load 
  `<script type="text/javascript"> setTimeout ( "doSomething()", 60000 );</script>`
- Inside doSomething() method write javascript code to hide the text.

  `function doSomething(){
      document.getElementById('msgid').innerHTML='';
  }`

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842614/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-on-page-load post for calling a javascript code on page load.

Comment: where do I attach this >>> <h4 align="center">${message} </h4>

Comment: you can assign an id to you h4 tag <h4 align="center" id="msgid">${message} </h4>

On body load call function 

<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout ( "doSomething()", 60000 ); //This will call function after 1 minute
</script>

function doSomething ( )
{
  document.getElementById('msgid').innerHTML=''; //this code will clear you msg
}

Comment: please edit your answer to include the comments. tnx

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in javascript call every minute to your controller which will be in function e.g. callController():

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   setTimeout(function(){ callController() }, 60000);
</script>
```

*60000 - is minute in milliseconds