# AJAX XMLHttpRequest Object

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have been working with script from w3schools.  I would like the ajax_info.txt file to appear as the page loads instead of with the button click.  I've seen this question before, but can't find the answer again after a couple of days of looking. I pre-apologize for this idiotic question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>

<p id="demo">Let AJAX change this text.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call a JavaScript function on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842614/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-on-page-load)

Comment: If you want a function to run on page load you can do this <body onload="loadDoc()">

Comment: In your case, just add `loadDoc()` after the function definition.