# How do I call a JavaScript function's on loading my html page?

Tags: javascript, html, load

I have a page that has some functions that I would like to load when the page gets loaded .. Currently the function is called only when a button is clicked, I would also like this to loaded on page load / refresh

```
function LOADMEONSTARTUP() {
    var reader = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');
    reader.open('get', 'log.txt', true);
    reader.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (reader.readyState == 4 && reader.status == 200) {
            displayContents1(reader.responseText);
        }
    };
    reader.send();
}

function displayContents1(content) {
    var wanted = 'apples';
    var words = content.split(/\s/);
    var found = [];
    words.forEach(function (word, index) {

        if (word === wanted && words[index + 1]) {
        found.push(words[index + 1]);
        }
    });
    console.log('found:', found);
    var el = document.getElementById('here1');
    el.innerHTML = found.length ? found.join('<br/>') : 'nothing found';
}
```

Comment: take a look at this article. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842614/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-on-page-load]

Comment: Maybe this could help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899701/815507

Comment: use window.onload = function();

Answer (score 1):

We can do that by adding an onload function to the body

```
<body onload ="LOADMEONSTARTUP()">
```

This can be achieved through Jquery where we use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
LOADMEONSTARTUP(); 
})
```

or you can refer to this post:

[Pure JavaScript equivalent of jQuery's $.ready() - how to call a function when the page/DOM is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t)

hope i helped :)

Comment: both work but I have 20 functions to load .. so it only loads like 5 of them and then stops when page loads :(

Comment: Are only 5 functions loading always? Or does it vary? If so you might need to check the architecture of your project with your higher ups..if it's only 5 errors...it can be a syntax error. There is no other reason why the javascript should stop loading anytime :)

Comment: only 5, it like when you browse to the site once the site loads it then stops

Comment: it might be a syntax error which is avoiding the entire code to execute..however i cannot be sure unless you show me the entire code that is being used here.