# How to Auto Click Button on Page load for my code

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onload

My button code is:

```html
<button class="button green-btn button--large marg20" onclick="searchMerchant();">
        <span class="uppercase trn" data-trn-key="search_restaurant">Search Restaurant</span>           
       </button>
```

How to autoclick this button on page load. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call a JavaScript function on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842614/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-on-page-load)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably the `document.onload()`-Trigger.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

```
document.onload = function() {
  searchMerchant();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    $(window).load(function() {

      $(".green-btn").click(function() {
       alert("your code or logic goes here on button click");
    });

    });
    </head>
```