# How i see which functions running when page is load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have no code for this. I need to know which functions are running from the page loads until its end.
like a list of functions (including jQuery), I need re-run them for some sort of task. I tried looking for some loggers and tools but found nothing but this [call JS function  on load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842614/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-on-page-load)

Comment: What about built in browser dev tools?

Comment: don't familiar with such, i have Firefox but don't know how to use it for this purpose

Comment: add `console.log('function name');`. Then look at console tab.