# I need to refactor this php function

Tags: php, html

I need to refactor this code, Im not a php developer so i dont understand the syntax thats apparent here, what i want is this button to activate the moment the page is loaded.

```
<?php

$h = '';

if ($newsermonstomove) {
    foreach ($newsermonstomove as $vettel) {
        $h .= "<div style=\"padding: 5px;\">";
        $h .= "<button id=\"btn_" . $vettel->ID . "\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs\" onclick=\"doMe(" . $vettel->ID . ");\" >s3</button><span style=\"padding-left:5px;\">Channel: " . $vettel->ChannelID . ", Sermon: " . $vettel->ID . " " . $vettel->SermonTitle . "</span> <div style=\"display:none;color:blue;\" id=\"msg_" . $vettel->ID . "\"></div><br/>";
        $h .= "</div>";
    }
} else {
    $h = "<h3>No new sermons.</h3>";
}

echo $h;
?>
```

From what i understand, the onclick has an escape in it `onclick=\"doMe(" . $vettel->ID . ");\"` In HTML i know that with a button if you do `onclick=doMe` its a reference to a function, which i feel like is the same thing thats happening here with the escape keys in it. its making a reference to the function doMe, but i want the function to fire automatically when the page loads.

Comment: `doMe()` is likely a JavaScript function, which you can [call on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842614/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-on-page-load).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233622/discussion-between-austin-howard-and-magnus-eriksson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i was able to figure out the answer I needed using JQuery.

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".btn").trigger('click');
    },10);
});
```

essentially what this function does is wait for the page to load then after 10 milliseconds it targets all buttons on the screen with the class name `btn` and triggers the click functionality of the button, thus firing off the button on the page load.

Answer (score -2):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php

    if (!empty($newsermonstomove)) {
        
        $h = '';
        
        foreach ($newsermonstomove as $vettel) {
            $h .= '<div style="padding: 5px;">';
            $h .= '<button data-id="' . $vettel->ID . '" class="btn-vettel btn btn-primary btn-xs">s3</button><span style="padding-left:5px;">Channel: ' . $vettel->ChannelID . ', Sermon: ' . $vettel->ID . ' ' . $vettel->SermonTitle . '</span> <div style="display:none;color:blue;" id="msg_'.$vettel->ID.'"></div><br/>';
            $h .= '</div>';
        }
        
    } else {
        $h = '<h3>No new sermons.</h3>';
    }

    echo $h;
?>

<script>
    $(function() {
        
        $('.bt-vettel').on('click', function(e) {
            
            var id = $(this).data('id'); 
            doMe(id);
            
        });
    });
<script>
```

[image]

Comment: From their question: _"i want is this button to activate the moment the page is loaded."_ This code won't do that. It's another improvement syntax wise though, but it still won't change the behavior.

Comment: What does it mean: i want is this button to activate the moment the page is loaded? What action should be fired once page is fully loaded (Click on the button with a special id or multiple button)?

Comment: That's what the original question says. If you wonder what it means, ask the OP. It's important that you read the question and ask for clarification _before_ attempting to answer.