# React useEffect runs but does not call function

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-hooks, function-call

I am trying to write a useEffect hook which will update the DOM once when the page loads. For some reason that I cannot fathom, the useEffect runs but the function does not get called. The `console.log()` on the other hand does get called.

There is no problem with the function itself, it works when I run it from the console or trigger it in some other way. I have also tried using different syntax for writing and/or calling the function, placing inside or outside the useEffect. The result is always the same—the DOM does not update but the `console.log()` logs.

Please help me, what am I doing wrong/ misunderstanding? Thank you in advance.

```
  // Add ids to h2 elements inside markdown
  useEffect(() => {
    function setID() {
      const H2List = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
      const H2Array = [...H2List];
      H2Array.map((a) => (
        a.setAttribute('id',
        `${H2Array[H2Array.indexOf(a)].childNodes[0].nodeValue
          .split(" ").join("-").toLowerCase()}`)
      ))
    }
    console.log("useeffect ran once");
    setID();
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more Googling, this works:

```
  window.onload = function() {
    setID()
  }

  function setID() {
    const H2List = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
    const H2Array = [...H2List];
    H2Array.map((a) => (
      a.setAttribute('id',
      `${H2Array[H2Array.indexOf(a)].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        .split(" ").join("-").toLowerCase()}`)
    ))
  }
```

Thank you to this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842614/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-on-page-load).

Answer (score -1):

if you want to update the dom you should cause a rerender in your app
define a state and setState your new data

Comment: Hi @mohammad gharouni thanks for replying. I was under the impression that with an empty dependancy array, a useeffect would run once with initial render, is this not the case? I'm happy to try usestate and report back.