# How do i make a JavaScript event run on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, onload, onmouseover

Im new to JS and replicated this effect according to a showcase of it that i saw which is supposed to "glitch" the text on hover and then make it go back to the original text.
This works by using `.onmouseover` and running the event after that. I tried changing this to `.onload` but then it wont run the animation/effect and i can't figure out why it does not work.

Here is my code:

```js
const symbols = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789"


document.getElementById("load-text").onmouseover = event => {
    let iterations = 0

   const interval = setInterval(() => {
    event.target.innerText = event.target.innerText.split("")
    .map((letter, index) => {
        if (index < iterations) {
            return event.target.dataset.value[index];
        }
        
        return symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * 35)]
   })
    .join("");

    if(iterations >= event.target.dataset.value.length) clearInterval(interval);

    iterations += 1 / 6;
}, 30);
}
```

```css
body {   
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #121012;
    justify-content: center;
}
.loader{
    margin-top: 40vh;
    color: #EEEEEE;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 30pt;

}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
    <p id="load-text" data-value="LOADER"> LOADER </p>
</div>
    <script src="project.js"></script>
```

(code pen: https://codepen.io/Tesked/pen/ExedNQX)

I have tried using possible solutions in this thread
[How do I call a JavaScript function on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842614/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-on-page-load)
but none of them seem to work, the event still doesn't fire unless i add the `.onmouseover` Where it works as it is intended to.

The idea here is to use this as a "loading screen" of sort that will do the glitch effect and then fade in the rest of the page, though this is a problem for another time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a small change on your JS code

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const symbols = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789";
  const target = document.getElementById("load-text");
  let iterations = 0;

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    target.innerText = target.innerText.split("")
      .map((letter, index) => {
        if (index < iterations) {
          return target.dataset.value[index];
        }

        return symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length)];
      })
      .join("");

    if (iterations >= target.dataset.value.length) clearInterval(interval);

    iterations += 1 / 6;
  }, 30);
};
```

i wrapped the function inside a `window.onload` tested on your pen seems working
could you try this and see if this is what you are expecting

Comment: If you click `[<>]` in the editor, you can make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You have to a couple more steps but the `DOMContentLoaded` event works for this. In order to then target it, you also need to search for the element in your DOM because `event.target` will be the document.

```js
const symbols = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789";
// Instead of `event.target` we have to select it first, as the target will be `document`
const element = document.getElementById('load-text')

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
  let iterations = 0;
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    element.innerText = element.innerText.split("").map((letter, index) => {
      if (index < iterations) {
        return element.dataset.value[index];
      }
      return symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length)]
    }).join("");
    if (iterations >= element.dataset.value.length) clearInterval(interval);
    iterations += 1 / 6;
  }, 30);
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #121012;
  justify-content: center;
}

.loader {
  margin-top: 40vh;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 30pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <p id="load-text" data-value="LOADER"> LOADER </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply trigger the event via:

```js
loadingTextEl.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseover'));
```

```js
const loadingTextEl = document.getElementById('load-text')
const symbols = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789"

const onMouseOver = (event) => {
  let iterations = 0
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    event.target.innerText = event.target.innerText.split("")
      .map((letter, index) => {
        if (index < iterations) {
          return event.target.dataset.value[index];
        }
        return symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * 35)]
      })
      .join("")

    if (iterations >= event.target.dataset.value.length) clearInterval(interval)
    iterations += 1 / 6;
  }, 30)
}

loadingTextEl.addEventListener('mouseover', onMouseOver)

loadingTextEl.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseover')) // Trigger
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #121012;
  justify-content: center;
}

.loader {
  margin-top: 40vh;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 30pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <p id="load-text" data-value="LOADER"> LOADER </p>
</div>
<script src="project.js"></script>
```

Comment: I mean, yeah, that's a solution. But it seems... confused. There already exist events that do exactly this that are better suited for this use case...?

Comment: @somethinghere I don't know if OP wants the mouseover event to remain on the element.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess.