JS Alert on pageload
I want to create an alert / message that shows me the users geodata after the page has been loaded.
Here ist the script for the geolocation that I want to be
displayed in the alert.


<script>
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}

alert("Your location is:" + getLocation());
</script>




It's not clear to me what you mean.  What is reloading the page?  What alert do you want to show the user?  What attempt have you made and what isn't working as expected?

hey, I just want an alert (popup) that shows the user's geodata (latitude & longitude) once the page has loaded. I need also a close button.

And what stops you from doing this?  What attempt have you made and what isn't working as expected?

I don't know how to do this. I'm a JS beginner

Please see Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

That's not very helpful. I don't even know how to start.

Start with the first problem you encounter.  If that first problem is "I don't know JavaScript" then a good first step would be to use your favorite search engine to find introductory tutorials on JavaScript.  If the problem is "I know some JavaScript, but don't know how to do X" (where X is a specific operation to be performed) then a good first step would be to use your favorite search engine to look for examples of X in JavaScript.  This community can certainly help with specific technical problems encountered along the way, but does not offer personalized tutoring services.

I have searched on google but I don't know how to combine something like   ""     and   ""     with the code above

Why not start by replacing the functions in the example you just gave (showAlert()) with the function(s) you wrote?

@vince: You'd start by understanding what the code is doing and defining what you want it to do.  "How to combine" is a non-starter because it doesn't define any of that.  For example, if you want to replace "Hello world!" with specific text then you'd start there.  What text do you want to replace it with?  What happens when you try?

I didn't write it myself. I googled it aswell. So the result would be something like:
 
You seem to already have a script part in your question.

@david I want to insert the geofindme () variable. It should output the users coordinates.

What do you mean by "insert the variable"? Insert it where?

@vince: What specifically do you mean by "the geofindme () variable"?  In your code geoFindMe is a function.  That function doesn't return anything.  Are you looking for the latitude and longitude variables in your success function?  In your code, do you see where those variables are?  Have you tried writing an alert operation there?  What is stopping you from trying anything at all?

so instead of "hello world" I want the code to be executed, so that the users coordinates are being shown. how do I achieve this in this context ? Insert the "geoFindMe()" funtcion somehow ?

That's what  <body onload="geoFindMe()"> does; did you try it?

@david I am not a webdesigner. I m just trying to combine pieces of code that I found online. Its like saying to a random stranger: why aren't you performing surgical operations ?

@vince: In your analogy, did that stranger approach a community of surgeons and ask them why his surgery isn't working as expected?  We can appreciate that you're struggling, but you may be misunderstanding what this community does.  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt.  To learn more about this community, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

@mykaf: well it doesn't show a popup / an alert message. How can I achieve this part ?

First, please [edit] your question to show the updated code; we need a [mre] to see the full picture. Using your browser's dev tools is a great way to debug code; check your console for errors.

@vince: "well it doesn't show a popup / an alert message" - If you're not familiar with your browser's debugging tools, now is a good time to start.  There could be a specific error that you're simply not observing.  Or the code may be executing successfully but you've overlooked something in the logic.  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

@mykaf: I just updated the original posting with additional information. Here you can see the button that I want to convert into an alert. "" alone didn't work. I need to integrate "alert" in the JS part somehow.

@vince: Given the code shown, I wouldn't be surprised if the browser produces an error (which you can confirm) on its development console indicating that geoFindMe isn't defined (or something similar in wording), since that function is defined later in the page than where it's being invoked.  Since the JavaScript code shown already makes use of addEventListener, I'd recommend taking the same approach when attempting to invoke a function on page load.

Buttons can't convert into alerts. Buttons are HTML elements; alerts are functions that display a message. But now I'm confused; why do you need a button if you want to display the alert upon page load? Page load only requires the user to navigate to the page; button clicks require the user to click the button? So you need to be clear about your expectations.

I am just showing a previous state -  the button isn't needed anymore. I want purely an alert that pops up after the page has loaded. I guess the script would be something like "$(window).on('load', function geoFindMe() {" ? And then I need to integrate "alert" somehow. Just not sure how.

You added an "click" event listener to the button; you can do similarly with "load" and "window."
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10367736/1599011

something like this: document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", geoFindMe); ?

What happens when you try it?

nothing...I think the "alert" needs to be integrated in the code.

ok, I just modified the code and put it in at the top. It outputs an popup but it says "undefined". Let me show you the code in the original post (editing right now).

Sounds like your need to debug the code that creates the string you pass to the alert.

oh, I realised the alert only came up because I had an old script in the header "function geoFindMe(msg) { alert(msg);}"

changed the whole thing up. just can't display the location coordinates (getLocation).

Okay, what does happen? Is there an alert at all?

Yeah, there is an alert which says „undefined“. I just can‘t seem to save the whole thing in a function and call it.

getLocation() is part of your alert, but getLocation() doesn't return anything, so the result of its execution is undefined. You have to return the value you want to include the alert string.

I tried the same with showposition(position) but this didn’t deliver any output aswell

Your functions are doing calculations, but don't hand anything back to their callers. You need to return something.

How do I do this?

Did you read the linked documentation?

Assuming the code executes without error (you haven't specified)... This should be successfully alerting "Your location is:undefined":
alert("Your location is:" + getLocation());

Because getLocation doesn't return anything.  Since the information you're looking for is asynchronous, it only exists in or after a given callback operation.  That callback operation (the function where the values you want exist) is:
function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}

So that's where you'd add your alert.  For example:
function showPosition(position) {
  const result = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

  x.innerHTML = result;
  alert(result);
}


Using your original example below...
NOTES:

I am not making this a runnable Stack Snippet because geolocation is disabled there.  It appears to work on CodePen though.
I also had to define x.  Which I assume you'd defined elsewhere in your code.  Otherwise what would you expect it to be and why?  And surely the browser would be producing an error on the console?

<script>
  const x = {}; // Whatever x is in your code isn't necessary in this example

  function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
      x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
  }

  function showPosition(position) {
    const result = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

    x.innerHTML = result;
    alert(result);
  }

  getLocation();
</script>


do I need to change the bodyonload part ? The alert doesn't appear at all right now.

@vince: With regards to the code shown in the question... What is "the bodyonload part"?  The code shown in the question appears to be successfully showing an alert.  If the alert isn't appearing at all, what were you referring to here?  Please update the question to include a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, and indicate specifically what problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.

I just tested your last code and the alert/popup didn't appear. By the bodyonload part I am referring to this part : " "

@vince: The code appears to be working when I test it.  Are you getting any errors on the browser console?  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  Also... "By the bodyonload part I am referring to this part" - That part isn't shown in the question.  I haven't taken into account any information you haven't provided, because you haven't provided it.  Please ensure the question includes a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

what I am trying to do is output an popup which shows the users coordinates (longitude & latitude)

@vince: That example is producing errors on the browser console.  If you're not familiar with your browser's debugging tools, now is a great time for you to start.  One of the two errors is unrelated to the code being asked about in the question.  The other, referring to the code in the question, is indicating that the variable x is never defined.  Where do you think you've defined it?  What value do you expect it to have and why?  Note that this answer does indeed already point this out.  Did you try defining x?  Removing the lines which use it?  Anything at all?

the original code has this line: "const x = document.getElementById("demo");"

I ve removed it because it refers to an html element "demo" which wouldn't work with an alert, right ? I am not sure how to refer to an alert.

@vince: If you've removed the code which defines x then you should probably also remove the code which uses x, since you can't use something that doesn't exist.  Which is why your code produces that error.  I guess you simply forgot to do that, and the error was essentially a typo.

well I removed it but I still don't have the alert/ popup window with the coordinates being shown

@vince: It's working as expected for me when I visit the page you previously linked.  If it's failing specifically in your browser and not other browsers then you may have some other problem that's specific to you.  In that case you'd likely need to debug further, checking for errors on the browser console and using the script debugger in your browser.

just checked in firefox it worked! just doesn't appear in chrome but that's fine. thank you!!!



function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  const result = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

  innerHTML = result;
  alert(result);
}

getLocation();




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
